# Disabling/Uninstalling gnome shell extensions via tweak tool not working

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I am trying to disable the following extensions via tweak tool

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/517/caffeine/

But its not working. They are being re-enabled automatically(when I reopen tweak tool, they are back). After disabling from tweak tool, I refreshed Gnome shell as well. Still they are getting enabled again. I tried with other extensions. Few are getting disabled and few aren't. What might be the issue ?

PS: Now even uninstalling isn't working. I tried various ways - removed from tweak took, deleted extensions manually from ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions directory. They are getting uninstalled first and then system onreboot or back from standby I am getting numerous prompts asking "Install the extension" as if I am actually trying to install the extension and even when I click cancel, the extensions are getting installed again automatically in few sec/mins !!!!

Using Ubuntu Gnome 16.04, 3.20.4 shell version

Comment: Have you tried disabling them from the website? https://extensions.gnome.org/local/

Comment: Tried.  same issue

Comment: I don't think there is another way to disable them. :( Have you tried removing them completly?

Comment: Yes, I tried disabling via tweak tool, removing via tweak tool, deleted the directories and then rebooted the system (repeated all this multiple times). Still the extensions keep getting installed/enabled.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did anyone get a workaround?